# Can't get android maps api v2 to work after releasing app

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-maps-v2

A few days ago I released my app, so I had to change my maps api debug key to a live key. 
Now I want to debug again and I have set back the debugging maps api key in AndroidManifest.xml, but the map stays blank after running my app.

I use Intellij as IDE.